# Messages are not automatically moved to dead letter channel (DLC) - broker - wso2 ei

Tags: wso2, message-queue, esb, broker, wso2-esb

Im using WSO2 EI 6.1.1 with Message Broker, and trying to create message queue with message store and message process with an endpoint.

When I shutdown my endpoint, the message processor is deactivated and the messages stay in the queue and they are not moved to DLC.

What should I do to make it work ?

Thanks,

Faris Shomou

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior with message processor / message store :

- A scheduled message processor will try to send the message until the
  delivery is successfull (and offers you a way to implement guaranteed
  delivery pattern)
- A sampling message processor will send the message
  in a non reliable way (it can be lost)

If you want to manage a JMS transaction and have the message to go in DLQ, use a jms inbound endpoint or jms proxy and set required parameters (transport.jms.SessionTransacted, transport.jms.SessionAcknowledgement : have a look to wso2 documentation https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/JMS+Transactions)

Message store / processor is used to implements Dead letter channel EIP : the jms store host the dead message and you don't want it to be moved elsewhere

Comment: Thanks Jean-Michel. What is the default behavior of DLC and how the message will be moved to DLC? I have thought that after retrying (using  message processor parameter : max.delivery.attempts ), the message will be moved to DLC.

Comment: But why the message processor parameter (max.delivery.attempts) is not working ?
I have configured this parameter to 5 par example, and the message processor was deactivate for the first attempt. 
The message processor should not be deactivates before reaching the max.delivery.attempts, yes or no ?

Comment: As far as I know, max.deliver.attempts value is used to deactivate the Message Processor after a given number of "failure". But I've always used "-1" (never wanted it to be deactivated). The focus point is the endpoint that must not be suspended : error codes = -1 for suspended state and timeout state

Comment: Thanks again Jean-Michel